# How to print out specific values from a list

Tags: python, string, list, printing, parentheses

Hey this might be a simple question, but i have been stumped on it for awhile =/

I have a string A:

```
A = ('A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5')
```

And a corresponding list B, that displays the exact position of each value inside the inner parenthesis of the string A:

```
B = [12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
```

I want to make a new list, list C that prints the values inside the parenthesis of String A, which is defined by the numbers in list B.

Thanks for the help!

Edit:
My goal is to create a list that just prints what is inside the inner parenthesis, something like this:

```
C = ('C:0.3,D:0.4')
```

I will then split at the comma, and input the corresponding 2 strings into another function i have defined, but right now, i just need list C

Comment: which python version supports such lists `B = [12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23]
`??

Comment: Please show your expected result. Your problem as stated makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Sean why the string A is inside `()`?

Comment: @Sean see my edited  solution below, but what's the use of `B` in fetching `('C:0.3,D:0.4')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> A = ('A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5')
>>> B = [12 ,13, 14 ,15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ,20 ,21, 22, 23]
>>> C=[A[x] for x in B]
>>> C
['(', 'C', ':', '0', '.', '3', ',', 'D', ':', '0', '.', '4']
```

**EDIT:**

```
>>> A = ('A:0.1,B:0.2,(C:0.3,D:0.4)E:0.5')
>>> C=A[A.find('('):A.find(')')+1]
>>> C
'(C:0.3,D:0.4)'
```

Comment: Note the syntax issues. The definition of A has superfluous parens that make it look like a one-element tupple, while the list B was missing it's commas which meant it raised a syntax error.

Comment: Ahh, thank you, that is what i was looking for, my actual lists A and B are not as easily defined as A = '', B = '' in my code, I just simplified it to make my question easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `B` really is a list,

It seems that you really only need `B[0]` and `B[-1]` for this:

```
print A[B[0]:B[-1]+1]
```

Or as a list:

```
list_of_chars=list(A[B[0]:B[-1]+1])
```

If at any point, `B` isn't sequential (works if `B` is sequential too):

```
list_of_chars=[A[i] for i in B]
```

will give you the list of characters...

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension may solve this:

```
C = [A[i] for i in B]
```